# Populate table view with dictionary data which was passed from previous view controller by notification

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, notifications

I want to populate my table view with this data:

```
3 key/value pairs
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "default"
    - value: "http://exampleURL1"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "classme"
    - value: "https://exampleURL2"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "alliance"
    - value: "https://exampleURL3"
```

I'm passing data from one view controller to another. Inside another view controller, I've created variables, to store the data:

```
var organizationData: [String : String] = [:]
var orgName: [String] = []
var orgImage: [String] = []
```

Here is the code, where I'm getting this data:

```
@objc func organizationDataIsReady(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let organizationDict = notification.object as? [String: String] {
            organizationData = organizationDict
            dump(organizationData)
            for (key, value) in organizationData {
                print("key is \(key) and value is \(value)")
                orgName.append(key)
                orgImage.append(value)
            }
        }
    }
    fileprivate func addTapGestureToUserAvatar() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AcademiesViewController.showProfileScreen))
        userAvatar.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
```

This I have in viewDidLoad method: *`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(organizationDataIsReady(_:)), name: Notification.Name.organizationReady, object: nil )`*

Here is my table view:

```
extension AcademiesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return orgName.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 300
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AcademiesCell", for: indexPath) as! AcademiesTableViewCell
        let key = orgName[indexPath.row]
        let value = orgImage[indexPath.row]
        cell.academyName.text = key
        let url = URL(string: value)
        cell.academyImage.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
        return cell
    }
```

So I need to make that, academyName should receive text from key and academyImage receive from value.

Comment: No, you don’t want two arrays of strings, you want one array with a custom struct containing two string properties. It will make your solution much easier. And you actually forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Not really understand